# Enable horizontal scrolling for a div, if childs total width is bigger than its width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to fit all of these blocks within their container on a single line.

The problem at hand is that the container has a fixed width of `300px`.

Each of the smaller `item`s has a width of `100px`

What I want to happen is for all of these `items` to be on a single line, and since their total `width` is more than the parent width, I want the parent to `overflow` in `x` with a scrollbar, but it all must stay contained within the `300px` width.

```css
.container {
  position: relative; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item {  
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  border:1px solid red;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="item">hi</span>
  <span class="item">hi</span>
  <span class="item">hi</span>
  <span class="item">hi</span>
  <span class="item">hi</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with css flexbox.

```css
#boxes {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.box {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #010101;
  background: #c8c8c8;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="boxes">
  <div class="box">Hi I'm box 1</div>
  <div class="box">Hi I'm box 2</div>
  <div class="box">Hi I'm box 3</div>
  <div class="box">Hi I'm box 4</div>
  <div class="box">Hi I'm box 5</div>
  <div class="box">Hi I'm box 6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `css flexbox`.

If you don't know this, you can learn about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item {  
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border:1px solid red;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="item">hi</span>
  <span class="item">hi</span>
  <span class="item">hi</span>
  <span class="item">hi</span>
  <span class="item">hi</span>
</div>
```

Give your `.container` `display: flex`, and then to prevent your `.item` from shrinking/growing, add `flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0;`.

`display: flex;` will put all children of the element in a single row (be default, you can manipulate direction with [`flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction)).

More about `flex-shrink`, `flex-grow` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex).

Also, you can replace properties `width: 100px; flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0;` with shorter syntax:

```css
.item {  
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `white-space: nowrap;` to the parent container. This will make the child elements to fall in same line.

```css
.container {
  position: relative; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  border: 1px solid black;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.item {  
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  border:1px solid red;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="item">hi</span>
  <span class="item">hi</span>
  <span class="item">hi</span>
  <span class="item">hi</span>
  <span class="item">hi</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using `flex-box` to the contianer and applying a `min-width` to childs.

```css
.container {
  position: relative; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
}

.item {  
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  border:1px solid red;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="item">hi</span>
  <span class="item">hi</span>
  <span class="item">hi</span>
  <span class="item">hi</span>
  <span class="item">hi</span>
</div>
```